# access static variable in view /master

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%=SessionManager.TimeOut%>" />
```

i tried this

SessionManager is a static class and TimeOut is a vlaible in the class set to 20

i am expecting

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20" />
```

to be rendered but

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%=SessionManager.TimeOut%>" />
```

is rendered

i am doing this in my master file

Comment: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%=SessionManager.TimeOut%>" /> how to render like  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20" />

Comment: You've asked 32 questions, so you should really know that BBCode doesn't work here by now. Could you please [spend some time with the editing help?](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) If you wait for volunteers to come along and make your questions legible, you may not get the answers you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `runat="server"` from your `<head>` :-)

So instead of:

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%=SessionManager.TimeOut%>" />
    ...
</head>
```

simply use:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%=SessionManager.TimeOut%>" />
    ...
</head>
```